# Is there a maximum number of different marker styles in google static maps api?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am  trying to create aseries of maps with markers. I have experienced, that when there is 5 or more markers shown at the same time, one of the markers are not rendered properly.

[Here is an example.](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=55.6651497,12.5627201&zoom=19&size=640x640&sensor=false&maptype=hybrid&markers=icon%3ahttp://tinyurl.com/35jf67s|55.6651497,12.5627201&markers=icon%3ahttp://tinyurl.com/2u2vdlg|55.6647231,12.5618896&markers=icon%3ahttp://tinyurl.com/3xh478c|55.6648916,12.5622652&markers=icon%3ahttp://tinyurl.com/37cfrf4|55.6651633,12.5626555&markers=icon%3ahttp://tinyurl.com/2vqhqve|55.6657588,12.5634301&markers=icon%3ahttp://tinyurl.com/35lte56|55.6655667,12.5629865)

As far as I can see, the icon url is correct, and if i remove one of the markers, it is shown properly..

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you find a way to deal with more markers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Static Maps API developer reference:

> "The Static Maps service allows up to
>   five unique custom icons per request.
>   Note that each of these unique icons
>   may be used multiple times within the
>   static map."

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/